# How to set up Service Discovery in Docker swarm with Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, docker-swarm, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am having difficulty setting up service discovery in a docker swarm.

I created a docker swarm on a linux machine:

`docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.172.123.4`

Then created an overlay network:

`docker network create -d overlay my-overlay`

Then added three services:

`docker service create --replicas 1 --name eureka -p 8761:8761 --network my-overlay eureka`

`docker service create --replicas 1 --name zuul -p 8761:8761 --network my-overlay zuul`

`docker service create --replicas 1 --name testapp -p 8761:8761 --network my-overlay testapp`

'eureka', 'zuul', and 'testapp' are all Docker images, that when run independently, all work together, and register with eureka, and I can interact with 'testapp' through the zuul proxy.

However...

When I run them as services in a swarm, they don't register with Eureka.  When I visit the Eureka page at 192.172.123.4:8761, I get this:

> Instances currently registered with Eureka:
>
> *No Instances*

How is it done?

---

These are my configs:

zuul:

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=zuul-server
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.serviceurl.defaultzone=http://192.172.123.4:8761/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

testapp:

```
server.port=8799
spring.application.name=duplo
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=false
eureka.serviceurl.defaultzone=http://192.172.123.4:8761/
```

eureka:

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    preferIpAddress: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

Answer (score 1):

When running zuul/eureka via spring-boot it will error if the port is already in use.

Try binding -p 8762:8762 for zuul and the -p 8799:8799 for testapp.

Not sure if you're getting a port is occupied error or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but I ended up following this tutorial and it worked perfectly - I would recommend this as a good starting point for people having issues setting up a stack like this:

https://github.com/binblee/springcloud-swarm